# How can I declare a member reference to a member static array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, reference, static

I have some legacy code that's set up like so in the header file

```
class Foo
{
    static double Params[];
}
```

and in the source file has the declaration done as

```
double Foo::Params[] = { 1, 2 };
```

Then later in various class functions it's referenced as

```
Params[0] = userValue;  // Change value in position 0.
```

Now I'm tasked with adding more Params arrays so that I'll have

```
class Foo
{
    static double Params1[];
    static double Params2[];
}

double Foo::Params1[] = { 1, 2 };
double Foo::Params2[] = { 3, 4 };
```

I don't want to muddy up the source code by doing this everywhere in the code

```
if (something) 
  Params1[0] = userValue;
else
 Params2[0] = userValue;
```

So I want to declare a reference to an array and just change the reference between Params arrays when 'something' is set so that I'm using the right parameters to read/write to. I've tried

```
class Foo
{
    static double Params1[];
    static double Params2[];
    static double (&Params)[];
    double(&NonStaticParamsTest)[];
}

double Foo::Params1[] = { 1, 2 };
double Foo::Params2[] = { 3, 4 };
double Foo::Params[] = Foo::Params1;  // Won't compile

Foo::Foo()  // Constructor
    NonStaticParamsTest(Params1),   // Also won't compile

// I'd like to switch between Params by moving the reference like this
if (something)
    Params = Params1;
else
    Params = Params2;
```

I've tried various changes on the syntax for both the static and non-static attempt at the reference but I'm just not quite there.

I've looked at this answer but the example doesn't involve classes or static variables so I can't quite get the accepted answer to work even when trying with auto variables.
[When Declaring a Reference to an Array of Ints, why must it be a reference to a const-pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827610/when-declaring-a-reference-to-an-array-of-ints-why-must-it-be-a-reference-to-a)

Is what I'm trying to do possible or does it not work with static arrays and classes?

Comment: C++ trains us all to be extremely case sensitive. That `Class` stands out as wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure any of this will work. Arrays can't be resized with assignment. You probably need `std::vector`.

Comment: The arrays aren't going to be resized and they are all of the same size. I'd change them to vectors except they are quite large in the actual code and it's not easy to pre-fill out vectors with values like you can arrays. So I'd hate to have to manually initialize vectors 1 line at a time for dozens of entries. Hence the array approach since it nicely initializes and is easy to read when someone is trying to see how it's filled out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here with the `(&Params)` notation. Do you want a reference to an array, or an array of references? Why can't you just use `std::vector<double> params1` and then have a reference to that? Why do you even need a reference?

Comment: I want a reference to an array. Like I said, changing to vectors will be a massive pain due to manually initializing them 1 line at a time instead of the nice way arrays can be initialized. My other option is to change to a pointer-to-array and just move the pointer but that will mean I have to change the code in all the functions and I'd really like to keep the code as it is so that Params[0] = value; still works.

Comment: You do realize you can initialize `std::vector` *exactly* the same way, I hope. The difference is almost invisible, especially to other code that uses it where `a[x]` works identically.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I've been used to the pre-C11 standard for so many years that I didn't realize that you could now initialize vectors like that. I just quickly changed the code to vector and added a non-static reference and it nicely compiled. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to declare a reference to an array and just change the reference between Params arrays when 'something' is set so that I'm using the right parameters to read/write to.

A reference can't be rebound once it has been initialized, so this won't work when `Params` is a reference:

```cpp
if (something)
    Params = Params1;
else
    Params = Params2;
```

You need a pointer instead, eg the following will work:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    static double Params1[];
    static double Params2[];
    static double (*StaticParams)[2];
    double (*NonStaticParams)[2];

    Foo();
    void doSomething();
};

double Foo::Params1[] = { 1, 2 };
double Foo::Params2[] = { 3, 4 };
double (*Foo::StaticParams)[2] = &Foo::Params1;

Foo::Foo()
    : NonStaticParams(&Params1)
{
}

...

if (something)
    Foo::StaticParams = &Foo::Params1;
else
    Foo::StaticParams = &Foo::Params2;

(*Foo::StaticParams)[0] = ...;
(*Foo::StaticParams)[1] = ...;

...

void Foo::doSomething()
{
    ...

    if (something)
        NonStaticParams = &Params1;
    else
        NonStaticParams = &Params2;

    (*NonStaticParams)[0] = ...;
    (*NonStaticParams)[1] = ...;

    ...
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/D5aiYU)